# Multiline array or lists syntax error

Tags: python, arrays, list

I haven't found anything that would help explain this on the web so far, and I think that it must be some goof up on my part. The problem is that while in Python 3.4 using Spyder2 as an IDE I keep getting a syntax error on my list and I need help understanding it.

So here is what I have tried.

- using '/' for a multi line statement.
- double checking for incorrect white space.
- Keeping the list's length smaller than the line.

When I kept the list relatively small it seemed to work just fine, but as soon as it goes over 76 characters is starts to give me this error:

> ```
> runfile('C:/Users/ghost/.spyder2-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/ghost/.spyder2-py3')
>   File "C:/Users/ghost/.spyder2-py3/temp.py", line 7
>     alphabet = [a = 0, b = 1, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5, f = 6, g = 7, h = 8,
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

**Code**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

This is a temporary script file.
"""
alphabet = [a = 0, b = 1, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5, f = 6, g = 7, h = 8,
            i = 9, j = 10, k = 11, l = 12, m = 13, n = 14, o = 15, p = 16,
            q = 17, r = 18, s = 19, t = 20, u = 21, v = 22, w = 23, y = 24,
            x = 25, z = 26]
print(alphabet)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is incorrect syntax. You have `[]` for a `list`, but you're assigning each value to another value, which is more like a `dict`, so that doesn't work. You can fix this with the smallest change by sending that to the `dict()` function to create a dictionary:

```
>>> alphabet = dict(a = 0, b = 1, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5, f = 6, g = 7, h = 8,
...             i = 9, j = 10, k = 11, l = 12, m = 13, n = 14, o = 15, p = 16,
...             q = 17, r = 18, s = 19, t = 20, u = 21, v = 22, w = 23, y = 24,
...             x = 25, z = 26)
>>> alphabet['b']
1
```

Comment: I am probably incorrect but I thought that a list would allow an array of variables? I was assuming that I would just assign a value to them inside the list.

Comment: Yes, it's an array of variables, like `mylist = ['a', 3, 91, 'hello']`.

Comment: If you want separate references (which I really really don't recommend, as it defeats the purpose of storing them in a `list`) you would have to assign them beforehand, then refer to them, with e.g. `a = 0`, and `b=1`, etc., then `mylist = [a, b]`. But don't do it that way.

Comment: I think that I understand now, so the actual variable name for the value 'a' in your comment is mylist[0] or it's position in the array. So dict allows the use of redefining a variable and value sort of?

Comment: Some languages allow you to do this by having assignment return the assigned value, but not Python.

Comment: The `dict()` function is just a function. You're calling it with named arguments just like you'd do with something like `print(sep='a', end='---')`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had been stuck on this for a bit. I'll vote that as the answer as soon as ten minutes is up.